# How to perform a transition on a simply component load with Vue.js

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component, vue.js

This is what the Vue.js documentation state:

> Vue provides a transition wrapper component, allowing you to add
>   entering/leaving transitions for any element or component in the
>   following contexts:

- Conditional rendering (using v-if)
- Conditional display (using
  v-show)
- Dynamic components
- Component root nodes

I just simply have a component that is loaded and filled out with XHR data though. How do I go about using a transition to show when the elements v-for gets the data array from an ajax request and builds up my template?

I want a nice fade in instead of simply "plopping" the data into the dom. and have it show up with a delay out of nowhere.

My components example:

https://jsfiddle.net/uwk1x1bx/

```
<template>
    <transition name="fade">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12" v-for="faq in faqs">
                <h2>{{ faq.description }}</h2>
                <div v-for="item in faq.items" class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">{{ item.description }}</div>
                    <div class="panel-body" v-html="item.answer"></div>
                </div><!-- /.panel -->
            </div><!-- /.col-md-12 -->
        </div><!-- /.row -->
    </transition>
</template>
```

JS

```
<script>
    export default {
        name: "Faq",

        data() {
            return {
                faqs: []
            }
        },

        created() {
            this.fetchFaqData();
        },

        methods: {
            fetchFaqData() {
                Vue.http.get('/services/getfaq').then((response) => {
                    this.faqs = response.data;
                }, (response) => {
                    console.log(response);
                })
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Please fix your fiddle to get it working without your server.. it is not working at all

Comment: @MU Obviously it is just a code example. I hardly doubt anybody would need a working example to come to the conclusion what to do here.

Comment: if you will fix your fiddle I will give you working solution :)

Comment: <transition appear> Ok thanks for all your wonderful help.

Comment: thanks for sharing mate